# Bs4 scrape table specifik

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I hope you guys are always healthy

I want to scrape a more specific table using BS4. this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'test.com'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

for row in soup.select('tbody tr'):
    row_text = [x.text for x in row.find_all('td')]
    print (row_text)
```

how do you get results like this:

```
    Number, Name, address, telp, komoditi
1, "ABON JUARA" JUARA FOOD INDUSTRY, Jl. Jend Sudirman 339, Salatiga, Jawa Tengah, 0298-324060, Abon Sapi Dan Ayam
```

and saved in CSV

Comment: name, addres and telp are all in a single td so you would need to parse them seperatly

Comment: can you help me to separate them

Comment: show us a sample of the expected output

Comment: Sample result in csv : No, Name, Address, Telp, Komoditi. 1, "ABON JUARA" JUARA FOOD INDUSTRY, Jl. Jend Sudirman 339, Salatiga, Jawa Tengah, 0298-324060, Abon Sapi Dan Ayam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.select_one("table#newspaper-a").select("tr[valign=top]")
    with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["No", "Name", "Address", "Tel", "Komoditi"])
        for item in target:
            item = list(item.stripped_strings)
            item[3] = item[3][6:]
            writer.writerow(item)


main("https://kemenperin.go.id/direktori-perusahaan?what=&prov=&hal=1")
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a78ea2325654c3bf4d1ae78d2f736034/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem and is no different from the OPs output, the issue is the middle column needs to be split into name, addr, tel columns

Comment: @ChrisDoyle thanks for the comment, just noticed that the OP updated the question. will handle it momently

Comment: Nice and clean.